# Reaction-Diffusion algorithm on Processing + Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, processing

I have made an implementation of the Reaction-Diffusion algorithm on Processing 3.1.1, following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV9ny785UNc). I have made some adaptations on my code, like implementing it on a torus space, instead of a bounded box, like the video.

However, I ran into this annoying issue, that the code runs really slow, proportional to the canvas size (larger, slower). With that, I tried optmizing the code, according to my (limited) knowledge. The main thing I did was to reduce the number of loops running.

Even then, my code still ran quite slow.

Since I have noticed that with a canvas of 50 x 50 in size, the algorithm ran at a good speed, I tried making it multithreaded, in such a way that the canvas would be divided between the threads, and each thread would run the algorithm for a small region of the canvas.

All threads read from the current state of the canvas, and all write to the future state of the canvas. The canvas is then updated using Processing's pixel array.

However, even with multithreading, I didn't see any performance improvement. By the contrary, I saw it getting worse. Now sometimes the canvas flicker between a rendered state and completely white, and in some cases, it doesn't even render.

I'm quite sure that I'm doing something wrong, or I may be taking the wrong approach to optimizing this algorithm. And now, I'm asking for help to understand what I'm doing wrong, and how I could fix or improve my code.

Edit: Implementing ahead of time calculation and rendering using a buffer of PImage objects has removed flickering, but the calculation step on the background doesn't run fast enough to fill the buffer.

My Processing Sketch is below, and thanks in advance.

```java
ArrayList<PImage> buffer = new ArrayList<PImage>();
Thread t;
Buffer b;
PImage currentImage;

Point[][] grid; //current state
Point[][] next; //future state

//Reaction-Diffusion algorithm parameters
final float dA = 1.0;
final float dB = 0.5;
//default: f = 0.055; k = 0.062 
//mitosis: f = 0.0367; k = 0.0649
float feed = 0.055;
float kill = 0.062;
float dt = 1.0;

//multi-threading parameters to divide canvas
int threadSizeX = 50;
int threadSizeY = 50;

//red shading colors
color red = color(255, 0, 0);
color white = color(255, 255, 255);
color black = color(0, 0, 0);

//if redShader is false, rendering will use a simple grayscale mode
boolean redShader = true;

//simple class to hold chemicals A and B amounts
class Point
{
  float a;
  float b;

  Point(float a, float b)
  {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  size(300, 300);

  //initialize matrices with A = 1 and B = 0
  grid = new Point[width][];
  next = new Point[width][];

  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
  {
    grid[x] = new Point[height];
    next[x] = new Point[height];

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
      grid[x][y] = new Point(1.0, 0.0);
      next[x][y] = new Point(1.0, 0.0);
    }
  }

  int a = (int) random(1, 20); //seed some areas with B = 1.0
  for (int amount = 0; amount < a; amount++)
  {
    int siz = 2;
    int x = (int)random(width);
    int y = (int)random(height);

    for (int i = x - siz/2; i < x + siz/2; i++)
    {
      for (int j = y - siz/2; j < y + siz/2; j++)
      {
        int i2 = i;
        int j2 = j;
        if (i < 0)
        {
          i2 = width + i;
        } else if (i >= width)
        {
          i2 = i - width;
        }
        if (j < 0)
        {
          j2 = height + j;
        } else if (j >= height)
        {
          j2 = j - height;
        }


        grid[i2][j2].b = 1.0;
      }
    }
  }
  initializeThreads();
}

/**
 * Divide canvas between threads
 */
void initializeThreads()
{
  ArrayList<Reaction> reactions = new ArrayList<Reaction>();

  for (int x1 = 0; x1 < width; x1 += threadSizeX)
  {
    for (int y1 = 0; y1 < height; y1 += threadSizeY)
    {
      int x2 = x1 + threadSizeX;
      int y2 = y1 + threadSizeY;

      if (x2 > width - 1)
      {
        x2 = width - 1;
      }
      if (y2 > height - 1)
      {
        y2 = height - 1;
      }

      Reaction r = new Reaction(x1, y1, x2, y2);

      reactions.add(r);
    }
  }

  b = new Buffer(reactions);
  t = new Thread(b);
  t.start();
}

void draw()
{  
  if (buffer.size() == 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  PImage i = buffer.get(0);

  image(i, 0, 0);
  buffer.remove(i);
  //println(frameRate);
  println(buffer.size());

  //saveFrame("output/######.png");
}

/**
 * Faster than calling built in pow() function
 */
float pow5(float x)
{
  return x * x * x * x * x;
}

class Buffer implements Runnable
{
  ArrayList<Reaction> reactions;

  boolean calculating = false;

  public Buffer(ArrayList<Reaction> reactions)
  {
    this.reactions = reactions;
  }
  public void run()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      if (buffer.size() < 1000)
      {
        calculate();

        if (isDone())
        {
          buffer.add(currentImage);

          Point[][] temp;
          temp = grid;
          grid = next;
          next = temp;

          calculating = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  boolean isDone()
  {
    for (Reaction r : reactions)
    {
      if (!r.isDone())
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  void calculate()
  {
    if (calculating)
    {
      return;
    }

    currentImage = new PImage(width, height);
    for (Reaction r : reactions)
    {
      r.calculate();
    }

    calculating = true;
  }
}

class Reaction
{
  int x1;
  int x2;
  int y1;
  int y2;

  Thread t;

  public Reaction(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
  {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  public void calculate()
  {
    Calculator c = new Calculator(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    t = new Thread(c);
    t.start();
  }

  public boolean isDone()
  {
    if (t.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED)
    {
      return true;
    } else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

class Calculator implements Runnable
{
  int x1;
  int x2;
  int y1;
  int y2;

  //weights for calculating the Laplacian for A and B
  final float[][] laplacianWeights = {{0.05, 0.2, 0.05}, 
    {0.2, -1, 0.2}, 
    {0.05, 0.2, 0.05}};

  /**
   * x1, x2, y1, y2 delimit a rectangle. The object will only work within it
   */
  public Calculator(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
  {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;

    //println("x1: " + x1 + ", y1: " + y1 + ", x2: " + x2 + ", y2: " + y2);
  }

  @Override
    public void run()
  {
    reaction();
    show();
  }

  public void reaction()
  {
    for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
    {
      for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++)
      {
        float a = grid[x][y].a;
        float b = grid[x][y].b;

        float[] l = laplaceAB(x, y);

        float a2 = reactionDiffusionA(a, b, l[0]);
        float b2 = reactionDiffusionB(a, b, l[1]);

        next[x][y].a = a2;
        next[x][y].b = b2;
      }
    }
  }

  float reactionDiffusionA(float a, float b, float lA)
  {
    return a + ((dA * lA) - (a * b * b) + (feed * (1 - a))) * dt;
  }

  float reactionDiffusionB(float a, float b, float lB)
  {
    return b + ((dB * lB) + (a * b * b) - ((kill + feed) * b)) * dt;
  }

  /**
   * Calculates Laplacian for both A and B at same time, to reduce amount of loops executed
   */
  float[] laplaceAB(int x, int y)
  {
    float[] l = {0.0, 0.0};

    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++)
    {
      for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++)
      {
        int i2 = i;
        int j2 = j;
        if (i < 0)
        {
          i2 = width + i;
        } else if (i >= width)
        {
          i2 = i - width;
        }
        if (j < 0)
        {
          j2 = height + j;
        } else if (j >= height)
        {
          j2 = j - height;
        }

        int weightX = (i - x) + 1;
        int weightY = (j - y) + 1;

        l[0] += laplacianWeights[weightX][weightY] * grid[i2][j2].a;
        l[1] += laplacianWeights[weightX][weightY] * grid[i2][j2].b;
      }
    }

    return l;
  }

  public void show()
  {
    currentImage.loadPixels();

    //renders the canvas using the pixel array
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
      {
        float a = next[x][y].a;
        float b = next[x][y].b;

        int pix = x + y * width;

        float diff = (a - b);

        color c;

        if (redShader) //aply red shading
        {
          float thresh = 0.5;

          if (diff < thresh)
          {
            float diff2 = map(pow5(diff), 0, pow5(thresh), 0, 1);

            c = lerpColor(black, red, diff2);
          } else
          {
            float diff2 = map(1 - pow5(-diff + 1), 1 - pow5(-thresh + 1), 1, 0, 1);

            c = lerpColor(red, white, diff2);
          }
        } else //apply gray scale shading
        {
          c = color(diff * 255, diff * 255, diff * 255);
        }

        currentImage.pixels[pix] = c;
      }
    }
    currentImage.updatePixels();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A programmer had a problem. He thought “I know, I’ll solve it with threads!”. has Now problems. two he

**Processing uses a single rendering thread.**

It does this for good reason, and most other renderers do the same thing. In fact, I don't know of any multi-threaded renderers.

**You should only change what's on the screen from Processing's main rendering thread.** In other words, you should only change stuff from Processing's functions, not your own thread. This is what's causing the flickering you're seeing. You're changing stuff as it's being drawn to the screen, which is a horrible idea. (And it's why Processing uses a single rendering thread in the first place.)

You could try to use your multiple threads to do the processing, not the rendering. But I highly doubt that's going to be worth it, and like you saw, it might even make things worse.

If you want to speed up your sketch, you might also consider doing the processing ahead of time instead of in real time. Do all your calculations at the beginning of the sketch, and then just reference the results of the calculations when it's time to draw the frame. Or you could draw to a `PImage` ahead of time, and then just draw those.

Comment: The actual rendering is not done in multithread, just the calculation. But as you said, the flickering probably comes from the data being manipulated while the sketch renders.
I'll try the alternative approaches you mentioned and come back with the results.

Comment: @tady159 If you're modifying data structures from one thread and using them to draw in the rendering thread, you're going to need to implement some kind of synchonization so you aren't changing stuff while it's being drawn to the screen. This will certainly not speed your program up.

Comment: I have implemented the ahead of time approach you suggested. I made a buffer containing PImage objects.
In the background, every time the calculation of a frame is done, a PImage is added to the buffer.
Although this removed the flickering, the background calculation isn't running fast enough, resulting in the buffer being mostly empty when the main thread of the Sketch is going to render to the canvas.

Comment: @tady159 You need to do this **ahead of time**. By that I mean, you could use a loop **in the `setup()` function** to pre-populate the buffer. Your program will take longer to start up, but then the rendering will be faster.

Comment: I tried making the rendering ahead of time, then I ran into the following:
If I close the running sketch before it is done filling the buffer, the entire Processing environment freezes.

It did run smoothly this time, but I have noticed this: although this is a deterministic algorithm, it's hard to predict how long it will take for it to reach a stable state. I've tried rendering 1000 frames ahead of time, and once it showed those frames, the reaction barely started.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but I ran out of space.
I also have noticed that the problem may note be much of optimization at this point, and for that I apologize. Checking my task manager, I saw that while the Sketch runs, my CPU usage goes to 100%, meaning that the Sketch isn't get enough resources to run.

Comment: @tady159 My answer was meant more as a general direction, not a full solution. You're going to have to play with it a little. 1000 frames is only 16 seconds. There are a bunch of things you could try. Maybe try exporting the frames as image files, and then loading those image files? But I don't really understand what you mean by your sketch not getting enough resources. If your CPU is at 100%, that means your sketch is getting 100% of the resources it possibly can.

Comment: By not getting enough resources I meant, if the CPU is at 100% usage, the Sketch wouldn't get any more processing power if it needs.
But anyway, since I can't figure out anything better, I'll stick with I have.
Thank you for your help